# Meteor Mongo query to return to return documents created within 24 hours

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm creating a simple app in Meteor that looks up items in the database and returns a count of the items that match username and were created within the last 24 hours.

If I remove the `createdAt` logic from the query the template loads the total number of entries in the database submitted by the user. With the `createdAt` logic the template renders `Loading` as declared in the helper conditional instead of the actual count.

In `/server/methods.js` I have:

```
    Meteor.methods({
      Counter: function () {
        return Items.find({
          username: Meteor.user().username,
          createdAt: {$gt: Date.now()*1000 - 24*60*60}
        }).count();
      }
    });
```

In `/client/home/helpers.js` I have:

```
    Template.home.created = function() {
        Meteor.call('Counter', function(err, result) {
            Session.set("theCounter", result);
        });
    };

    Template.home.helpers({
      counter: function() {
        return Session.get("theCounter") || "Loading";
      }

    });
```

And then in `/client/home/home.html`

```
    <template name="home">
        Submitted In Last 24 Hours: {{ counter }}
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong with the code:

First, `return Session.get("theCounter") || "Loading";` will always display "loading" if the counter is 0. You need to do:

```js
var c = Session.get('theCounter');
if (c != null)
  return c;
else
  return 'loading';
```

Next, the date math is incorrect. `Date.now()` is already in milliseconds, so you need to modify your query like so:

```js
Date.now() - 24*60*60*1000
```

Comment: I've made the changes. Now it always shows a count of 0.

Comment: Are you sure those items exist in the database for that user? I.e. they are all written with the correct dates?

Comment: I'm storing them in like this `createdAt: new Date()` and here is an example of one of the records retrieved: Wed Mar 18 2015 14:33:26 GMT-0400 (EDT)

Comment: Sorry bad example because that one doesnt meet the 24 hour criteria. But there are several that exist in the database that have been completed just a few hours ago!

Comment: Well with some simple debugging you should be able to isolate the issue. Try removing the date selector, but keep the user selector. Is a count returned? If yes, try adding back the selector and making the date way in the past (new Date('1/1/13')). Maybe there is something going on with your `created` callback or maybe the session variable is being overwritten somewhere else.

Comment: A correct count does return with the date selector removed. Manually setting the session also displays properly.

Comment: Also I can insert a new record with a 2013 date as you have suggested and my count is still showing 0.

Comment: Try the same query in the mongo shell: `meteor mongo`. Then do `db.items.find(...).count()` with the appropriate username and date. Also try console logging the `result` returned in the `created` callback to verify it's also 0.

Comment: Mongo shell returns 0 as well as result when I console log it.

Comment: If the shell returns 0, then I think we can conclude the data isn't stored correctly.

Comment: That's odd. As mentioned I'm storing the data like this: `new Date()` for createdAt. I will continue to troubleshoot and research. Thanks for the help.